# C# XNA Русские символы

Tags: c#

Не получается решить проблему с выводом Русских символов в xna 3.1

вот пример xml

**gamefont.spritefont**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<XnaContent xmlns:Graphics="Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Graphics">
    <Asset Type="Graphics:FontDescription">
        <FontName>Courier New</FontName>
        <Size>32</Size>
        <Spacing>2</Spacing>
        <Style>Arial</Style>
        <CharacterRegions>
        <CharacterRegion>
                <Start>&#32;</Start>
                <End>&#126;</End>
        </CharacterRegion>
        </CharacterRegions>
    </Asset>
</XnaContent></CharacterRegions>
        </Asset>`enter code here`</XnaContent>
```

Мне уже приходилось решать такую проблему, я находил контент процессор на msdn. Но решение не сохранилось.

Если кто нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой, пожалуйста подскажите.

Answer (score 1):

В `<CharacterRegions></CharacterRegions>` расположены области символов для создания шрифта. В данном случае можно добавить ещё один `<CharacterRegion>`, а в его тегах `<Start>` и `<End>` указать соответственно начальный и конечный Unicode-номера символов для импорта.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй поменять кодировку `(<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>)` на ANSI

Comment: Это явно неверно. В файле не используются символы, не входящие в ANSI, а для них кодировка utf-8 совпадает с ANSI.